# Android I Need 1 Superscript Character in the MIDDLE of a String in the Middle of an Array

Tags: java, javascript, android, character-encoding

Now I saw TONS of options for this but none of them will work for me or are far too indirect for me to sort of uh, extrapolate it to what I need.

What I have is a list view and there's only a few places I need to use a superscript 6, however I cannot for the life of me find the way to do this in a data list array...

The main java behind the activity:

```js
    Cadence_list cadence_list_data[] = new Cadence_list[] {
        new Cadence_list("Perfect Authentic", "V→I", "V→i", "strongest", "must been in root position with tonic doubled in soprano", "definitive end of a section/piece"),
        new Cadence_list("Imperfect Authentic", "V→I", "V→i", "extremely strong", "V to tonic with one or more inverted or not containing tonic in soprano; V7, vii° and vii°⁶ subsitute for V", "firm end of a section/piece"),
        new Cadence_list("Half", "any→V", "any→V", "weak", "---", "creates a desire to continue on"),
        new Cadence_list("Phrygian Half", "---", "vi⁶→V", "weak", "V7 can substitute for V", "creates desire to continue, particularly to a faster section"),
        new Cadence_list("Lydian Half", "---", "iv⁶→V", "weak", "entire iv⁶ chord is raised ½ step", "exactly like Phryigian half, only with a more discordant beginning"),
        new Cadence_list("Plagal", "IV→I or ii⁶→I", "iv→i", "weak", "usually preceeded or followed by stronger cadence", "reverential sound requiring absolution with or following a stronger cadence"),
        new Cadence_list("Deceptive", "V→not I", "V→not i", "moderate", "cannot go to I in major or i in minor", "generates feeling for resolution then denies resolution, causing unease")
    };

    Cad_listAdapter adapter = new Cad_listAdapter(this,
        R.layout.cad_list_layout, cadence_list_data);

    cad_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.cad_list);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cad_list_head, null);
    cad_list.addHeaderView(header);
    cad_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The custom constructor (Cadence_list):

```js
    public class Cadence_list {
        public String cad_name;
        public String maj_prog;
        public String min_prog;
        public String strength;
        public String restrict;
        public String feel;
        public Cadence_list() {
            super();
    }

    public Cadence_list(String cad_name, String maj_prog, String min_prog, String strength, String restrict, String feel) {
        super();
        this.cad_name = cad_name;
        this.maj_prog = maj_prog;
        this.min_prog = min_prog;
        this.strength = strength;
        this.restrict = restrict;
        this.feel = feel;
        }

    }
```

The custom Adapter (Cad_listAdapter):

```js
    public class Cad_listAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cadence_list> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        Cadence_list data[] = null;


    public Cad_listAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Cadence_list[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;   
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        Cad_listHolder holder = null;


        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new Cad_listHolder();
            holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.cad_name);
            holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.maj_prog);
            holder.txtTitle3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.min_prog);
            holder.txtTitle4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.restrict);
            holder.txtTitle5 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.strength);
            holder.txtTitle6 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.feel);

            row.setTag(holder);

        }

        else {
            holder = (Cad_listHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Cadence_list cadence_list = data[position];

        holder.txtTitle1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtTitle2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtTitle3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtTitle4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtTitle5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtTitle6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.txtTitle1.setText(cadence_list.cad_name);
        holder.txtTitle2.setText(cadence_list.maj_prog);
        holder.txtTitle3.setText(cadence_list.min_prog);
        holder.txtTitle4.setText(cadence_list.restrict);
        holder.txtTitle5.setText(cadence_list.strength);
        holder.txtTitle6.setText(cadence_list.feel);

        return row;

    }

    class Cad_listHolder {
        TextView txtTitle1;
        TextView txtTitle2;
        TextView txtTitle3;
        TextView txtTitle4;
        TextView txtTitle5;
        TextView txtTitle6;
    }

}
```

So you can see where they are there, and that's inside of a data array. How can I get those to work?

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter for the listview? If so, can you post its code?

Comment: Yeah, custom adapter and constructor, I will edit the post to include all of it.

Comment: Edited to include all relevant code.

Comment: So, you'd like to find the `superscripts` and display them properly in your `ListView` items. Can we assume that the superscript is always the number `6`?

Comment: Well, for the moment yes, always the number 6. I can probably figure out later how to get a 6 over a 4 on the same line with no divider (like a fraction without a divider), but that's a way down the road. So yes, always the number 6. Also it isn't showing above, but the degree character (I can't remember if it displays properly or not, I only know the superscript 6 does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using HTML [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) here. The superscript html tags `<sup></sup>` tags are used to introduce the superscript notation which "6" (simplest) regular exp is used to replace all instances of `6` to <sup>6</sup>. I am sure that you can come up with better and much more powerful regexes to control the output.

This is code you should try:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    Cad_listHolder holder = null;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new Cad_listHolder();
        holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.cad_name);
        holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.maj_prog);
        holder.txtTitle3 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.min_prog);
        holder.txtTitle4 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.restrict);
        holder.txtTitle5 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.strength);
        holder.txtTitle6 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.feel);

        row.setTag(holder);

    }

    else {
        holder = (Cad_listHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Cadence_list cadence_list = data[position];

    holder.txtTitle1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.txtTitle6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    holder.txtTitle1.setText(Html.fromHtml(cadence_list.cad_name.replaceAll("6", "<sup>6</sup>")));
    holder.txtTitle2.setText(Html.fromHtml(cadence_list.maj_prog.replaceAll("6", "<sup>6</sup>")));
    holder.txtTitle3.setText(Html.fromHtml(cadence_list.min_prog.replaceAll("6", "<sup>6</sup>")));
    holder.txtTitle4.setText(Html.fromHtml(cadence_list.restrict.replaceAll("6", "<sup>6</sup>")));
    holder.txtTitle5.setText(Html.fromHtml(cadence_list.strength.replaceAll("6", "<sup>6</sup>")));
    holder.txtTitle6.setText(Html.fromHtml(cadence_list.feel.replaceAll("6", "<sup>6</sup>")));

    return row;

}
```

Comment: I take it that I have to replace the "⁶" character above with 6 for this to work? Now, using the HMTL sup, will that alter the line height? Also, would that method work by replacing it with Charcterset encoding and pasting the ⁶?

Comment: `I take it that I have to replace the "⁶" character above with 6 for this to work?` What do you mean? The code above will replace the `getView()` method that you currently use. And, yes, you should add a bit of padding to your `TextViews`. Say, `android:paddingTop="5dp"`. That should do it.

Comment: It did work, but the number itself is too big (though it is superscripted and showing). So if I wanted to use the Unicode character, how would I go about that?

Comment: Actually I went into Eclipse and set the text encoding to UTF-8 and it renders the ⁶ properly when I export, but it's just as big as the HTML super, I just need to add in some code to alter the size. Thanks, definitely worked.

Comment: Yea, I was looking for a solution to this for you, but haven't been able to figure it out. I got as far as knowing that the `unicode` character that you require is `\u2076`. But, I haven't been able to render it. It shows up as a blank space. Hope you have better luck.

Comment: Well, I had to make sure the text in Eclipse was encoded as UTF-8 (it wasn't) before I exported the app. Now the issue is that, although it works without the above code, it may not always work on all devices so I'm going to go with that and now I just need to adjust the size of that 6 so that it is a bit smaller, but relative to the rest of the text and not a set size (differing resolutions and what have you).

Comment: I learned quite a bit about Unicode today, lol. Was hoping to get you the whole solution.

Comment: Well, you did get me the full solution in a way of how to get superscript into the array, which is what I was primarily looking for. The rest I can probably find out on my own, thank you though.